# How to subtract multiple day range from current date

Tags: sql, teradata

Using Teradata -
I know I can subtract days from current date by Current_date -7, but I need to subtract multiple day options from a date field. Say my data field is Completed_Date and I need to pull any dates that are from 7 - 14 days prior to that date. So today being 5/20/2022, it will pull records with completed dates from 7 -14 days ago - 5/6/2022 - 5/13/2022

Hope I've made that clearer than mud...

Thanks,
Kim

Comment: Use between?  `where completed_Date between current_date  -15 and current_date -7`

Comment: Initially that didn't work, but once I flipped  the -7 and -15 it worked perfectly... thank you!

Comment: Tried to edit my comment but took too long to do... no switching was required... worked exactly as you wrote it... thank you!